# Clear a text input field when a DropDown Selection field is set to a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the HTML Selection form field below, I need to reset a text field value when the selection field is set to any value besides `Completed` or `Cancelled`

```
<select name="status" id="status" title="">
    <option label="Open" value="Open">Open</option>
    <option label="In Progress" value="In_Progress">In Progress</option>
    <option label="Future_Project" value="Future_Project">Future_Project</option>
    <option label="Cancelled" value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option label="Completed" value="Completed" selected="selected">Completed</option>
</select>
```

The Text input that I need to set the value to empty/nothing looks like this...

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="date_completed_date" value="09/20/2014 06:15pm" size="11" maxlength="10" onblur="combo_date_completed.update();" onchange="combo_date_completed.update(); ">
```

I can use jQuery or regular JavaScript.  I would appreciate any help, I think this should be pretty simple?

Comment: @PM77-1 perhaps it being too late for me to think as clearly as I generally do, I don't have a good or valid excuse but I got the help I requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its worth retaining the Date if the user Re-selects another Option otherwise the date will stay Blank.

```
var date = $('#date_completed_date').val();
$("select").on("change", function () {

    if ($(this).val().indexOf('ed') == -1) {
   $('#date_completed_date').val('');
}
    else { 
        $('#date_completed_date').val(date); 
    }

})
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/mrw9hor8/

Comment: You're right, that's a really nice added touch, thanks for sharing!  I like it!

Comment: Its ok, i put that in there for a WHAT IF situation, :))

Answer (score 5):

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bevanr01/7e2ubo85/4/

```
$( "#status" ).change(function() {
    if ((["Cancelled","Completed"].indexOf($(this).val()) == -1)){
         $('#date_completed_date').val('');   
    }
});
```

And if you wanted to get fancy as mentioned below you could add today's date those two values are selected.

```
$( "#status" ).change(function() {
    if ((["Cancelled","Completed"].indexOf($(this).val()) == -1)){
         $('#date_completed_date').val('');   
    } else {
            $('#date_completed_date').val(new Date());   
    }
});
```

Comment: Another way to handle the if statement is:
    ```if (["Cancelled","Completed"].indexOf($(this).val()) == -1)```

Comment: Yes multiple ways to check the value. I was more focused on the `change` event.

Comment: I feel silly seeing just how easy this was, thanks for the answer =)

Comment: Just looking at the JSFiddle, it seems when you change the selection to `Cancel` that it is clearing the value, i'm not sure why, the code looks correct to me but it seems that value is ignored, any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you re-select (Cancelled) as an example

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <form name="sample">
    <select name="status" id="status" title="" onchange="clearInput()">
        <option label="Open" value="Open">Open</option>
        <option label="In Progress" value="In_Progress">In Progress</option>
        <option label="Future_Project" value="Future_Project">Future_Project</option>
        <option label="Cancelled" value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        <option label="Completed" value="Completed" selected="selected">Completed</option>
    </select>
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="date_completed_date" value="09/20/2014 06:15pm" size="11" maxlength="10" onblur="combo_date_completed.update();" onchange="combo_date_completed.update(); ">
</form>
```

in your script

```
function clearInput() {
   if(document.sample.status.value != "Completed" && document.sample.status.value != "Cancelled")
   {
     document.getElementById('date_completed_date').value='';
   }

}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't reset the text value when the select value changes. It also doesn't check when the value is ``Completed``

Comment: You'll need to attach an event listener to the ```<select>``` in order to get the desired effect. See Russell's answer.