# how to use JavaScript for reseting text field value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii1.x

I have following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->labelEx($model, 'membership', array('class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label')) ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->dropDownList($model, 'membership', array(Yii::t('member', 'Yes'), Yii::t('member', 'MO')), array(
                'class' => 'form-control',)); ?>

    </div>
    <?= $form->error($model, 'membership') ?>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <?= $form->textField($model, 'question', array('class' => 'form-control dotted')) ?>
    <?= $form->error($model, 'question') ?>
</div>
```

I need to develop a JavaScript file which resets textField, when user chooses 'NO' option from the drop down menu. How can I do it?

Comment: You would do so with an if else clause

Comment: now you have 5 solutions,  please try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear a text input field when a DropDown Selection field is set to a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955477/clear-a-text-input-field-when-a-dropdown-selection-field-is-set-to-a-certain-val)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// for Id selector
document.getElementById('element_id').value = '';

// for class selector
document.getElementsByClassName("element_class").value = '';
```

Comment: also add when drop down value change as NO.

Answer (score 1):

you can create javascript function like

```
function myFunction(val) { 
    if(val=='NO') 
    { 
        document.getElementById('element_id').value = ''; 
    } 
}
```

and call it like this:
`<select onchange="myFunction(this.value)">`

Answer (score 1):

Try `JS/JQuery`. apply `onchange` function in `dropdown`. In function check selected value and if it is NO then empty text field by using id

below `text_field_id` is id of your     text field

```
<?= $form->dropDownList($model, 'membership', array(Yii::t('member', 'Yes'), Yii::t('member', 'MO')), array(
                'class' => 'form-control','onchange'=>'validate(this.value)')); ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(value)
        {
            if(value == 'NO') {
           document.getElementById('text_field_id').value = '';

          }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all add onchange function in `<select>` as:

```
<?=$form->dropDownList($model, 'membership', array(Yii::t('member', 'Yes'), Yii::t('member', 'MO')), 
array('class' => 'form-control','onchange'=>'getAlert(this.value)')); ?>
```

Than in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getAlert(value){
    if(value == 'No'){
      document.getElementsByName("membership").value = '';
    }
  }
</script>
```

[YII Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/42803-yii-dropdown-onchange/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "selector_class_or_id" ).change(function() {

var selected_value = $(this).val();

if(selected_value === 'NO'){
   $("textField_class_or_id").val('');
}
});
```

Comment: jQuery not tagged